# Square brackets causing error in URL string in android

Tags: java, android, url

Hi im having a problem with executing a URL in Android, I am sure it is related to the square brackets but I cant find any solution. Any suggestions would be welcome.

```
  protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {


            int indexdevice = 12;
            String uuu = URLEncoder.encode  ("http://<ipaddress>/ZWaveAPI/Run/devices[2].instances[0].commandClasses[0x25].Set(255)", "UTF-8");
            HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String SetServerString = "";
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uuu);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget,responseHandler);
            Log.v("NAS", "--------- amount is  " + SetServerString);

        } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
            Log.v("NAS",String.valueOf(ex));
            }
```

The error I am getting is:

```
 07-08 12:37:33.970: V/NAS(1800): java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are url encoding the complete url, including http and hostname. That won't work. Just encode the part after the host address:

```
String uuu = "http://<ipaddress>/"+URLEncoder.encode  ("ZWaveAPI/Run/devices[2].instances[0].commandClasses[0x25].Set(255)", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply im getting the following error now 07-08 12:56:42.700: V/NAS(1967): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null

Comment: I modified my post, I shifted the first slash of the path url part into the server part. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks its working now .. Gratefully appreciated.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

the http:// is probably getting encoded try something like 
String foo = foo.replaceFirst("http://", ""); foo = "http://"+ foo

Comment: Yep it looks like "http%3A%2F%2F"

Comment: It is encodes, not just probably, as he calls URLEncode on the complete string.

Comment: I have changed that just now but im getting the error I mentioned brummfondel post

Comment: I would make sure I am using the correct ip address, especially if you are on a VM on your rig you have to point it at the ip address your network assigned your computer, not your local host(assuming local dev. here)